# How to change website scale? Live Preview extention for Visual Studio Code

Tags: website, visual-studio-code, scaling

I use Live Preview extention for Visual Studio Code (Windows). Is there any way to change or reduce scale of website preview?
I tried using Ctrl + Plus/Minus - it affects the whole Visual Studio Code UI, not website. Ctrl + Mouse Scroll also do not work.